# CRTP derived() method in multiple level inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I am wondering why the follow does not work:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base0 {
    const auto& derived() { return static_cast<const Derived& >(*this);}
}

template<typename Derived>
struct Base1: Base0<Base1<Derived>> {
    auto foo () { return derived().foo_impl();}
}

struct Foo: Base1<Foo>> {
    auto foo_impl () { return "foo";}
}
```

It complains  that `derived()` is not a member. Changing `derived()`  to `this->derived()` works, but I guess this will get `Base1<Base0<Foo>>&` instead of `Foo&` (which is not desired), right?

Alternatively, we can do the follow:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base0 {
    const auto& derived() { return static_cast<const Derived& >(*this);}
}

template<typename Derived>
struct Base1: Base0<Derived> {
    // for some reason, "this->" is still needed here, why??? 
    auto foo () { return this->derived().foo_impl();}
}

struct Foo: Base1<Foo>> {
    auto foo_impl () { return "foo";}
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the conventional way of doing multilevel inheritance using CRTP. Any comments?

Comment: `derived` is a dependant type name and so requires `this->` or `Base0<Base1<Derived>>::`

Comment: There is not real conventionnal way. This is more of an opinion matter than technical

Comment: I can't believe it is not a duplicate, yet I can't find one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) (the question is not about `typename` or `template` *per se*, but the root cause is the same -- dependent name.)